# GraphViz - Link Edge Label to Another Dot Graph

Tags: svg, graphviz, dot

I've been looking for a solution to this but I cannot seem to find one for linking an edge label to another GraphViz Dot Graph. For example, if I have a graph called 'mydotimage2.svg' produced from the following:

```
digraph G
{
    graph [compound = true];

    subgraph cluster_0
    {
        node [style = bold];
        "A" "B" "C";
    }

    subgraph cluster_1
    {
        node [style = bold];
        "One" "Two" "Three";
    }

    "A" -> "One" [lhead = cluster_1, ltail = cluster_0, label = "Falafel", href = "~/workspace/GraphViz/mydotimage1.svg"]
}
```

If I create the 'mydotimage2.svg' SVG image in my terminal via:

```
dot -T svg mydotimage2.dot > mydotimage2.svg
```

The image opens just fine in my browser, and the edge label from A to One in the produced image is clickable, but does not open mydotimage1.svg which is in the same GraphViz directory as well. Does anyone know how to do this? I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use relative paths. 
That is, instead of `href = "~/workspace/GraphViz/mydotimage1.svg"` use `href = "./mydotimage1.svg"`

BTW, instead of using pipe redirection(`>`) you can specify desired output file name as a parameter to the `dot`.
Just append `-omydotimage2.svg` to the command line.
Where "mydotimage2.svg" is the file name you want to write to.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

And thanks, I started with GraphViz by doing "dot -T svg -O <filename>.svg" but I was writing python scripts to generate the dot code and svg images and got used to pipe redirection. Is it harmful to do it that way?

Comment: Don't think there will be any problem using pipe redirections if you prefer to use it.  
Just pointed out in case you overlooked this key.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I observe on my machine, I guess it's a general problem:

`graphviz` does expand the tilde `~` to but it does not remove the tilde. In my case I see `/home/rainer/~/workspace/GraphViz/mydotimage1.svg` as image location when I click on the hyperlink in the graph. That obviously doesn't exist. Looks like a bug to me...

The solution / workaround is to replace the `~` in the script with your home folder path, in my case

```
href = "/home/rainer/workspace/GraphViz/mydotimage1.svg"
```

which works as expected.

Comment: Thank you! This method worked as well and probably is good to know in general so that the images don't need to be in the same folder in order to open one another.

Comment: Yeah both absolute path (like my suggestion) and relative path (as per @user882813) work, it's just the `~` that is buggy. And: It may be different depending upon OS but for the output file you need to use a lower case character: `dot -T svg -o <filename>.svg`. `>` should be as good though.